# My question about zbMATH is closed as duplicate but it is not

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question

I'd like to have my question [ZbMATH and conflict of interest](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/97841/zbmath-and-conflict-of-interest) reopened. It needs a vote or two more.

The claimed duplicate is [Under what circumstances is there a conflict of interest for a researcher to be a reviewer of a submitted academic paper?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/72010/under-what-circumstances-is-there-a-conflict-of-interest-for-a-researcher-to-be).

Reasons:

- zbMATH is a collection of post-publication reviews of articles, not a peer reviewed journal. As such, the standards for having a conflict of interest might be different.
- zbMATH reviews are not anonymous. Peer reviews usually are. This might also influence what is and is not a conflict of interest.

Answer (score 3):

I think that is a pretty clear case for a difference, I like how you edited the question to make the case clearer. If there is anything useful in the comments, you may want to edit that in also.

Comment: I think most of the comments are obsolete or not relevant to begin with and can be deleted with no loss of anything of importance.